# Let $\phi_a$ be the automorphism of $G$ given by $\phi_a(x) = axa^{-1}$. Show that $|\phi_a|$ divides $|a|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism

**Assumption: Let $a$ belong to a group $G$ and let $|a|$ be finite.** 
I proceeded as follows: 
 Let $|a|=m.$We have
$\phi_a (x)=axa^{-1}$ and so $(\phi_a(x))^2=(axa^{-1})(axa^{-1})=ax(a^{-1}a)xa^{-1}=ax^2a^{-1}\implies (\phi_a(x))^m=ax^ma^{-1}$. 
**From here, how do I show that $(\phi_a(x))^m=x$?** Since, $e(x)=x$, we'll have $(\phi_a)^m=e$ and the result will follow. Note that $e$ is the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
$$\begin{align}
\phi_a^2(x)&=\phi_a(\phi_a(x))\\
&=\phi_a(axa^{-1})\\
&=a(axa^{-1})a^{-1}\\
&=a^2x(a^{-1})^2.
\end{align}$$ Let $H_a$ the group generated by $a$ there exists a morphism $f:H\rightarrow {\rm Aut}(G)$ defined by $f(x)=\phi_x$, let $K$ be the kernel of $f$, $|{\rm Im}(f)||{\rm Ker}(f)|=|H|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have understood. But then a lot more can be deduced since $(\phi_a(x))^m=x=ax^ma^{-1}\implies x^{m^m}=x\implies |x|$ divides $m^m -1$?

Comment: You made a mistake in your computations, $\phi_a^2(x)$ is not $\phi_a(x)\phi_a(x)$, but it is $\phi_a(\phi_a(x))$.

Comment: Is it? But $(f(x))^2=f^2(x)$ for example $(\sin x)^2= \sin ^2 x$. This is the usual interpretation of $(f(x))^m$ unless it is explicitly mentioned? Am I right?

Comment: No,$ f^2(x)=f(f(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* More generally, if $\phi: G \to H$ is a homomorphism of groups and $a \in G$ has finite order, then the order of $\phi(a)$ is finite and divides the order of $a$. Apply this to $\phi: G \to Aut(G)$ given by $\phi(a)=\phi_a$.